# numpy.equal with nested lists

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'll want to search a rectangle in a picture. The picture is gathered from PIL. This means I'll get a 2d-array where each item is a list with three entries for the colors.

To get where's the rectangle with the searched color I'm using `np.equal`. Here an shrunk down example:

```
>>> l = np.array([[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,0]])
>>> np.equal(l, [2,1])  # where [2,1] is the searched color
array([[False,  True],
   [ True,  True],
   [ True, False],
   [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

But I've expected:

```
array([False, True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

or

```
array([[False,  False],
   [ True,  True],
   [ False, False],
   [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

**How can I achieve a nested list comparison with `numpy`?**

Note: and then I'll want to extract with `np.where` the indexes of the rectangle out of the result from `np.equal`.

Comment: May be an overkill depending on what you want to do, but you can perform TEMPLATE MATCHING (looking for a fixed-structure object in a picture) with `scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate` and gettng the positions where correlation is maximum with `result[numpy.argwhere(result == result.max())]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `all` method along the second axis:

```
>>> result = numpy.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 0]]) == [2, 1]
>>> result.all(axis=1)
array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

And to get the indices:

```
>>> result.all(axis=1).nonzero()
(array([1]),)
```

I prefer `nonzero` to `where` for this, because `where` does [two very different things](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) depending on how many arguments are passed to it. I use `where` when I need its unique functionality; when I need the behavior of `nonzero`, I use `nonzero` explicitly.